# Routing field in elasticsearch via tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to use elasticsearch via tire gem for a multi-tenant app. The app has many accounts with each account having many users.

User Model:

```
  include Tire::Model::Search
  mapping do
    indexes :name, :boost => 10
    indexes :account_id
    indexes :company_name
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json( :only => [:name, :account_id, :company_name], 
       )
  end
```

I would like to add the routing based on account_id. Please help how this can be achieved.
I see that there are two ways to specify the routing.

1. during Mapping using the routing field
2. Using aliases

I'm interested in the first option. I see that _routing can be added to mapping section as a hash.

```
  mapping :_routing => { :required => true, :path => :account_id } do
    indexes :name, :boost => 10
    indexes :account_id
    indexes :company_name
  end
```

Search Query:

```
  User.tire.search do
    query do
      filtered do
          query { string('ovamsikrishna@gmail.com') },
          filter :term, :account_id => 2
      end
    end
  end
```

Do we need to specify anything in the search query? The indexing is not happening when I specify the mapping as specified above (with routing). Without routing it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the account_id as path helps you to accumulate all the same account data on 1 shard.

It is recommended to use the routing in the search query also to avoid hiting the search query 
on every shard.

Use the [Get Mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping.html) to verify the mapping is set properly or not.